# How do we include language locale in Fatfree framework in PHP

Tags: php, namespaces, fat-free-framework

I am new to Fatfree ,when I tried to include locale in my project, its not working.

1. index.php

   ```
   $f3->set('LOCALES', 'locales/;'.DICTIONARY);
   ```

   2.tree structure

   ```
   /app
   /locales
   /config
   /index.php
   ```

Comment: If it is what I think, your folder is /locale in the tree structure. Not locales

Comment: Oops!, that was a mistake

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly is not working? And also what's the value of `DICTIONARY`?

Answer (score 0):

You must set the translations directory:
$f3->set('LOCALES','dict/');

Then set the language to use:
$f3->set('LANGUAGE','en');

Inside your dict folder, you must create one php file for each locale.
Example en.php and so on ...

Check https://github.com/bcosca/fatfree for more details.